# SQL: select number of records

Tags: sql

How to find out the number of records returned by a query?

For example, I have one table named `Items` and each item has one subtype id. How can I find out the number of rows for the item which belongs to subtype 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following Query.

```
select count(*) from items where item_subtype_id=1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you read an introduction to SQL?

```
select count(*) 
from items
where subtype = 1
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from Items where subtype_id = 1
```